# Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1 endpoint programatically when running Azure InternalEndpoint locally in Emulator

Tags: .net, wcf, azure, iis-express, azure-emulator

I'm having trouble getting my local environment to run my desired Azure deployment in the emulator.

I have one WebRole `(MyWebSite)` that has a public (InputEndpoint), and one WebRole that has an InternalEndpoint `(MyServiceApplication)`. The InternalSite has a set of WCF services that it exposes to the PublicSite.

i.e.

```
  <WebRole name="MyServiceApplication"  vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="MyInternalEndpoint" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InternalEndpoint name="MyInternalEndpoint" port="8083" protocol="http"></InternalEndpoint>
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
  <WebRole name="MyWebSite" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
```

I connect to MyServiceApplication endpoints programtically from MyWebSite. ie.

```
var applicationRole = RoleEnvironment.Roles["MyServiceApplication"].Instances.First().InstanceEndpoints["MyInternalEndpoint"].IPEndpoint;
var endPointAddress = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/MyService.svc", applicationRole.Address, applicationRole.Port);
var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(endPointAddress));
```

The `endPointAddress` variable turns out to be `http://127.0.0.1:8083/MyService.svc` at runtime in Azure Emulator Express, however it complains:

> There was no endpoint listening at `http://127.0.0.1:8083/MyService.svc` that could accept the message.

However, when I browse to this endpoint via `http://localhost:8083/MyService.svc`, I have no issue.

So I guess the question is, how can I get the InternalEndpoint to bind to `127.0.0.1` in Azure Emulator Express (as opposed to localhost), or is there a way that I can programmatically resolve the endpoint to be `http://localhost:8083/MyService.svc`?

Hope someone can help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that is interested, both roles bind to 127.0.0.1 (as opposed to localhost) when I run Visual Studio with Administrator privileges.

Not entirely sure why this is the case, but it has done the trick for me.